# Help us choose the new Chiphacker.com Logo

Tags: discussion, design

We have setup a Design Challenge Designbay.com .

From the design challenge the following logos have been submitted (see the answered questions below).

If you think you can make a better logo, submit it as an answer bellow!

Help us choose the new Chiphacker.com logo by voting up your favorite logo.

Cheers,

Marcus

Comment: Just throwing this in the pot as different direction of inspiration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_Emblem
though I doubt any style like this would fit

Comment: Is the octopus important to the logo?

Comment: Yeah, what's with the octopus?

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Comment: too angry. where's the octopus?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Comment: This one has had the most effort put into it

Comment: I like this - maybe more personality in the eyes? It certainly has had thought put into the idea

Comment: This one was the closest to the original brief of lots of different components held in an Octopus' arms. 

~ Marcus

Comment: the best so far. i like how it single-colors.

Comment: I like this one too. Not sure on the bottom blue bar, but I think the illustration is great.

Comment: It's a bit complicated... ideally a logo should look good at any size and resolution.

Comment: text font on the middle text is VERY good but the octopus is a bit... "childrens comic book" -like, very well drawn though.

Comment: agree about jeanne's comment.   it is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: Cute. Not sold on the chiphacker text. But the character is tops :D

Comment: Cute....wrong number of arms!

Comment: unclear what he's carrying in his non-enough arms.  not a fan of cooper black font for this.

Comment: I think it is nice but when it is in red it seems to fit quickly in with Sparkfun. Meaning, if I saw sparkfun and this chip hacker logo in some links i would assume they are related if not from the same group. This could be a good thing, btw. just a thought. But it has my vote, for sure

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: i dont know about the glasses....but besides that....very cool

Comment: Yeah I like this one a lot! ~ Marcus ;-)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: Im a bit undecided about this one. Its very clean and polished but no reference to electronics in the logo (little resistors or something).

Comment: Plus I first read it as chiphocker. Although it is the best of the bunch.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the colours on this

Comment: the black background and white text looks pretty cool, one of the best with maybe some cool color shading/gradient colors.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: too cute!! well drawn though

Comment: Sort of cool but the color is too bland

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: too simple and caterpillar seems to have a low iq

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: I like the text and the green colored one. Would look better showing the components in the tentacles.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: really like this one

Answer (score 0):

[image]